# Thymeleaf with Spring MVC error No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using a code downloaded from web, a sample of Spring MVC+Hibernate+Maven+Spring data and in this code the pages are jsp. Now I would like to introduce Thymeleaf instead of jsp si I have created an HTML greeting page but when I go on this page I obtain this error

> 09:16:23.622 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dpr-data/WEB-INF/pages/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcher'

These are my files code:

Controller

```
package com.spr.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.spr.exception.ShopNotFound;
import com.spr.model.Shop;
import com.spr.service.ShopService;
import com.spr.validation.ShopValidator;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/shop")
public class ShopController {

    @Autowired
    private ShopService shopService;

    @Autowired
    private ShopValidator shopValidator;

    //Used to validate data
    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(shopValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newShopPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("shop-new", "shop", new Shop());
        return mav;
    }

    //@Valid means that shop has to be validate
    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createNewShop(@ModelAttribute @Valid Shop shop,
            BindingResult result,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors())
            return new ModelAndView("shop-new");

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        String message = "New shop "+shop.getName()+" was successfully created.";

        shopService.create(shop);
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/index.jsp");

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);   
        return mav;     
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView shopListPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("shop-list.jsp");
        List<Shop> shopList = shopService.findAll();
        mav.addObject("shopList", shopList);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editShopPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("shop-edit");
        Shop shop = shopService.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("shop", shop);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editShop(@ModelAttribute @Valid Shop shop,
            BindingResult result,
            @PathVariable Integer id,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws ShopNotFound {

        if (result.hasErrors())
            return new ModelAndView("shop-edit");

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.html");
        String message = "Shop was successfully updated.";

        shopService.update(shop);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);   
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteShop(@PathVariable Integer id,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws ShopNotFound {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.jsp");     

        Shop shop = shopService.delete(id);
        String message = "The shop "+shop.getName()+" was successfully deleted.";

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}

}
```

WebAppConfig:

```
    package com.spr.init;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.thymeleaf.dialect.*;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.spr")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.spr.repository")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

//  @Bean
//  public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
//      UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
//      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
////        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
//      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
//      return resolver;
//  }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename(env.getRequiredProperty("message.source.basename"));
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
        dialects.add(new LayoutDialect());

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*", "js/*", "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Initializer

```
package com.spr.init;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
                new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>spr-data</display-name>

</web-app>
```

pom file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spr-data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spr-data</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spr-data</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>dpr-data</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf dependecies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency to fix JSPServletException -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL dependncies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.log4jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

project structure

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/mcccw9.png]

what is the problem?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any thymeleaf configuration in your code. try adding following to your config class

```
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
        dialects.add(new LayoutDialect());

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*", "js/*", "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }
```

[for more details](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect)

Comment: Thanks, I have hadded this code to my WebAppConfig.java but I receive an exception at startup (maybe the above pom is wrong?)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/dom/Attribute
 at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect.<clinit>(LayoutDialect.groovy:49)

Comment: use this dependency instead  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You also have to remove UrlBasedViewResolver bean from your config class

Comment: I have updated above post, but now I receive Error resolving template "pages/greeting", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: if you are using my config then you dont need to put .html in the controller class just use the file name. this should solve your problem. in your case return "greeting";

Comment: yes I have already removed .html but when I go on http://localhost:8080/dpr-data/shop/greeting
I receive the above error.
I have inserted also the project structure

Comment: your resolver.setPrefix("/"); make it resolver.setPrefix("/pages/"); in the config file

Comment: I resolved with resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");